# Removing a Dictionary Entry With a Regex

Tags: c#, regex, linq

I'm trying to delete an entry from a dictionary (NOTE: Associative Array context).  The deletion is based on a given number. Any number of keys can contain that number plus other text.  What I'm doing currently is..

```
var results = from result in CGlobals.orders.Keys
              where Regex.IsMatch(result, cmbJobNum.Text + "*")
              select result;

foreach (string result in results)
    CGlobals.orders.Remove(result);
```

I'm getting an invalid operation exception, which states that the collection was modified.  What am I doing wrong here and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is the deferred execution in LINQ. Use this:

```
var results = (from result in CGlobals.orders.Keys
              where Regex.IsMatch(result, cmbJobNum.Text + "*")
              select result).ToList();

foreach (string result in results)
    CGlobals.orders.Remove(result);
```

Explanation:
The deferred execution feature in LINQ executes the query not where you define it, but only when you enumerate it, i.e. in the `foreach` loop. This means, you are looping over the `CGlobals.orders.Keys` enumeration and at the same time removing items from the dictionary which will update the keys enumeration.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that LINQ produces its results as you ask for them rather than all at once. 
You need something like `foreach (string result in results.ToArray())`.